# Understanding riot.js feature of creating modular applications

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I understand how riot.js enables a way to trigger and handle custom events. I also understand how templating is enabled by this library. However I do not understand the riot's pattern of creating and enforcing what it calls "modules that extend the core". Here is what riot offers in its extremely sparse (and only) article available on the web:

```
var instance;

global.admin = riot.observable(function(arg) {

    if (!arg) return instance;

    if ($.isFunction(arg)) {
        admin.on("ready", arg);
    } 
    else {
        instance = new Admin(arg);
        instance.on("ready", function() {
            admin.trigger("ready", instance);
        });
    }
});
```

How exactly does this pattern work and how does it help make the application core extensible? Thank you.

Comment: This question would be for Riot v1 (from looking at the question date) and out of date. Riot v2 has "mix-ins" which might be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Declare variable which will hold application instance.
var instance;

// Define observable admin function to be able to trigger and listen events.
global.admin = riot.observable(function(arg) {

  // Call admin() returns the application instance. 
  if (!arg) return instance;

  /* Call admin(function(arg){...}) will call a function 
     when "ready" event is triggered in admin function 
     passing the application instance as arg to function. 
     In that way presenters are started in riot-admin demo. 
     All models should trigger / listen events on instance 
     and presenters should listen / trigger events on instance (which is observable) 
     thus providing loose coupling of components. 
     Instance itself can play Mediator role */
  if ($.isFunction(arg)) {
    admin.on("ready", arg);
  } 
  else {
    /* Call admin(non_function_argument) is treated as initialization of application 
       with arg being a config object. Admin(arg) returns observable */
    instance = new Admin(arg);

    // Listen to instance's "ready" event. "Ready" is triggered somewhere in Admin(arg).
    instance.on("ready", function() {
      /* Trigger "ready" in admin function to call all functions 
         passed with admin(function(arg){...}) call earlier passing instance as arg. */
      admin.trigger("ready", instance);
    });

    // Add this line if Admin(config) is purely sequential.
    // instance.trigger("ready");
  }
});

/* Hope this will help a bit. But you should see it yourself in browser debugger to understand it clearly. */
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting this. I checked for a couple of days and had given up any help on this. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: One update - if Admin(config) is purely sequential you will have to trigger "ready" event in instance manually. If the code is sequential and event is triggered inside Admin(config) then instance.on("ready",...) will never happen as this line is interpreted after the event is triggered inside Admin(config). I've edited the answer.